# Is it possible to calculate the concentration percentage using chromatography paper?

Tags: concentration, chromatography

I'm trying to calculate the concentrations of specific compounds using paper chromatography. Would I be able to calculate a rough estimate by comparing the size of each concentrated spot? If not is there another way to calculate this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You must be thorough. To have a better resolution, place your mixture in two small points very close "oo" instead of one big "o". It is best to calibrate the TLC system using the compounds you are looking for (if available). Then measure not only the area of spots, but also their optical density.

Comment: Aweomse, thank you. I hadn't thought about using multiple spots for better consistency. Unfortunately, I don't have a spectrophotometer as these tests will simply be at my office instead of a lab. That does give me a good start and something to hopefully buy down the road. I'll most likely be using this method more and more often if all goes well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done.

I have done it on silica plates to compare the content of a natural product in different samples of plants. 
It is , obviously, better to use HPLC, but in that case the sample preparation was very tedious so we decided to do it through TLC. 
The content in the different samples was between 0 and 2%. Standards equivalent to a content of 0.5, 1, 1.5 and 2% we're prepared.

What you need to have succes is to be very accurate in the quantity that you apply on the plate and to have a good developer. 
The quantities applied must be all the same, preferably not too much because then the spots are very big and it is more difficult to compare them. 
Our product was developed with $\ce{KMnO4}$ yielding an intense yellow spot on a purple background.

Comment: Very cool, thank you for the answer. I think that the case I will be using this for will be a relatively unknown concentration of each compound. Hopefully, with several tests, I'll get an estimate anyway. Thanks again for your help!